# PANDAS : consolidate lines with lambda function into one line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame where I need to perform similar steps for a one column like in the example below:

```
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',',''))
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('.',' '))
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('-',' '))
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].str.strip()
```

Is there any way to consolidate all these steps into one line just for sake of not repeating the lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method chaining.  You can also use `.str.replace` instead of the lambda function.  Finally you can use regex to replace all of those symbols at once:

```
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = (
    dfd_landing['Supplier name']
    .str.replace(r'[,.-]','', regex=True)
    .str.strip()
)
```

I like to format method chains by putting everything inside paratheses and starting each method on a new line.  I typically think of the `.str` method as more of a prefix than a method to I keep it on the same line as the main string method I am trying to use.

Sample input:

```
dfd_landing = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier name': [', foo.-bar ']})
```

Output:

```
  Supplier name
0        foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned simple code snippet and minor modification in your code should work for you:

```
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',','').replace('.',' ').replace('-',' ').strip())
```

Sample input:

```
dfd_landing = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier name': ['A,asda', 'B.asdas', 'C-asdasd', ' D ', 'E '],})

  Supplier name
0        A,asda
1       B.asdas
2      C-asdasd
3            D 
4            E
```

Code and Sample output:

```
dfd_landing['Supplier name'] = dfd_landing['Supplier name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(',','').replace('.',' ').replace('-',' ').strip())

Supplier name
0         Aasda
1       B asdas
2      C asdasd
3             D
4             E
```